# Проверка выполнения правил рокировки в шахматах?

Tags: python

В правила шахмат сказано что для рокировки нужно обязательно чтобы для короля и ладьи это был первый ход. Вычисления одной лишь позиции фигуры для установления точных правил возможна ли рокировка недостаточно, нужно еще как минимум сделать счётчик ходов.
Отображение фигур у меня происходит следующим образом: циклом прохожу по двумерному массиву и если нашли совпадение тогда рисуем спрайт:

```
for y in board:
    for x in y:
        if x == 'leftRook' or x == 'rightRook':
            black_rook()
```

Если первый ход у Короля и соответственно первый у leftRook или rightRook тогда возвращаем True. Однако можно ли избежать такой переопределённости в названиях и оставить лишь Rook , то есть из этого :

```
board = ['leftRook', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'King ', ' ', ' ', 'rightRook']
```

это:

```
board = ['Rook', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'King', ' ', ' ', 'Rook']
```

Однако как же в таком случае считать ход, ведь название одно и то же, класс один, и если даже определить параметр "first_move" и передавать его в `__init__` вместе со значениями "x", "y" то такая конструкция сработает только на одной из ладей и один раз, ведь названия совпадают. Как же считать для каждой ладьи её ходы отдельно в случае когда у левой и правой ладьи одинаковые названия?

```
class Figure(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class black_rook(Figure):
    "" правила хода ""

class white_rook(Figure):
    "" правила хода ""
```

Comment: *Вычисления одной лишь позиции фигуры для установления точных правил возможна ли рокировка недостаточно, нужно еще как минимум сделать счётчик ходов.* Я бы просто добавил фигуре свойство WasMoved. Изначально False, при любом ходе = True.

Comment: Смотря как вы храните количество ходов. Если вы используете словарь, то как ключ используйте объект, а не его имя.

Comment: @Akina , у меня тоже была такая идея.  Сейчас цикл проходит по каждой клетке и затем рисует спрайт. По сути я не меняю позицию фигуры а делаю "начальную клетку" откуда стартовала фигура пустой, а "конечной" соответственно даю имя leftRook и получается что цикл заново рисует фигуру и тем самым все её свойства в __init__ преобретаются по новой. Как по другому сделать пока не знаю

Comment: И пересмотрите вашу реализацию доски. Особенно интересен в этом ключе пробел в строке короля.  Используйте объекты(ссылки) вместо строк.

Comment: Не забывайте о варианте, когда фигура двигалась, но в текущий момент занимает то же положение, что и в начале партии. Рокировка в этом случае всё равно запрещена. Кстати, альтернативный вариант - это флаг CastlingPossible, который на каждом ходе контролирует все три фигуры (или поля), и при первом же изменении сбрасывается.

Comment: @This4fun, на доске лучше хранить не строки, а ссылки на объекты (фигуры), там где нет объекта - там `None`. При перемещении объекта (в том числе и рокировке) просто записываем этот объект на новом месте, а на старом записываете `None`. Новый объект при этом не создается.

Comment: @insolor , как эти объекты поместить на доску? Создать класс Rook  и затем создать экземпляр " rook = Rook() " и на доску поместить экземпляр rook?

Comment: @This4fun, да, примерно так

Comment: @This4fun, и для каждой ладьи свой экземпляр.

Comment: @insolor, но ведь тогда будут плодиться экземпляры rook1, rook2, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @This4fun, у вас будет 4 экземпляра ладьи на всю игру (2 белых и 2 черных), и все. Ничего плодиться не будет.

Answer (score 0):

В целом, лучше на доске хранить не строки с названиями фигур, а объекты. Можно сделать общий базовый класс для фигур (примерно как у вас показано в вопросе). Все общие методы и свойства, не зависящие от вида фигуры, нужно поместить в этот класс (например, я бы сделал бы пустое правило перемещения в базовый класс, и туда же добавил метод определения возможных ходов для фигуры, а в каждой отдельной фигуры просто менял бы правила перемещения, а возможные ходы рассчитывались бы из метода базового класса).

Отдельные классы для белых и черных фигур создавать не нужно: можно просто в объекте указать какому игроку принадлежит фигура.

При перемещении по доске фигура записывается на новое мест, на старом месте записывается `Null`. Новый объект при этом создавать не нужно, просто старое значение записывается на новом месте. Объекты при этом не плодятся (при всех перемещениях у вас как было в начале игры 4 экземпляра ладьи (по 2 на каждого игрока), так и останется).

Конкретно для рокировки можно в базовый класс добавить флаг, перемещалась ли фигура с начала игры или нет. По этому флагу и определять одно из условий возможности рокировки.